# Loading packages in a Shiny app R package using Docker

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I have a shiny app where packages are loaded using `library()` in the **server.R** file. This works, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.

When I converted this app into an R package, I removed the `library` calls. Added a DESCRIPTION file and an R file in which I created a function like this:

```
...
#' @importFrom tidyr gather spread
#' @importFrom viridisLite viridis inferno magma plasma
#' @importFrom writexl write_xlsx
#' @export
#' 
run_my_app <- function(display.mode="normal",launch.browser=TRUE,...) {
  appDir <- system.file("app", package="mypackage")  
  shiny::runApp(appDir,display.mode=display.mode,launch.browser=launch.browser,...)
}
```

Once the package is installed, run `library(mypackage)` and run the function `run_my_app()` which launches the app in the browser. Everything works.

Now, I am dockerizing this app/R package. I am trying two ways and it doesn't seem to work. This is the first approach (only showing relevant code from the **Dockerfile**).

```
RUN mkdir /srv/shiny-server/mypackage
RUN Rscript -e 'system(paste0("cp -r ",system.file(package="mypackage"),"/app/* /srv/shiny-server/mypackage"))'
RUN sudo chown -R shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server

EXPOSE 3838

# run shiny server
CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

When run like `docker run --rm -p 127.0.0.1:3838:3838 myimage`, this launches the app correctly, but functions from dependency packages do not work, probably because I do not have any `library()` or `require()` calls.

This is the second approach (just like how a user would use the shiny app r package) which avoids most of the above script.

```
EXPOSE 3838
RUN Rscript -e 'library(mypackage);mypackage::run_my_app(port=3838,host="127.0.0.1",launch.browser=FALSE)'
```

But I already get stuck at the docker build image since it starts running the app during the build and the app doesn't work properly either.

Sure, I could skip the R package part and just use the shiny app in docker, but that involves having to maintain another set of code. I think I would prefer to keep the shiny app as an R package.

How is the best way to work with libraries while dockerizing a shiny app R package?

Comment: Can you include samples of `server.R` and `ui.R`, as well as the error message(s) you are receiving? It is [not recommended to use library() inside of a package](https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html) (see section 11.2).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there are multiple ways to launch a shiny app inside a docker container. And they differ in how they work. Details are discussed [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/different-ways-to-start-a-shiny-app-inside-docker/20828).

I have ended up choosing the first method (For reasons discussed in the above link) and keeping the `library()` calls. The calls have been moved to a file `functions.R` (has other helper functions) which is sourced from `ui.R` and `server.R` like `source("functions.R",local=TRUE)`. Not sure if the `local=TRUE` is needed. Saw it recommended elsewhere.

Details on how to handle NAMESPACE/`library()` calls and using a shiny app inside R package is not entirely clear to me. Since the helper functions inside `functions.R` is used in `ui.R` and `server.R`, I source them in both. It is not clear to me which file is executed first.

The second method didn't work because I should have used `CMD` rather than `RUN`. Something like this:

`CMD ["R", "-e", "mypackage::run_my_app(port=3838,host='127.0.0.1',launch.browser=FALSE)"]`